# LINQ - null exception on getting certain cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, null

I'm a greenhorn when it comes to LINQ. I've read some null exceptions and most of them pointed out

> ... in sth.AsEnumerable() ...

as root of the problem.

I've run into:

> The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

I tried to retrieve

> fieldname

from TrashPlaces (it has 2 fields only - id and name) by string Id I get from UserPlace record (UserPlace has 2 keys - 1 is userId that can be retrieved from AspNetUsers and the other is TrashPlace id). I've run into null problem on this LINQ code:

```
        public ActionResult JsonResult()
        {
            var users = db.AspNetUsers;

             //this was added, so I could root out mismatch in the queryId
            var nameformyuser = User.Identity.Name;



 //the null starts here and no-shock it goes further (meaning query is null  and 
 //can't do nothing later)

            var queryId = from user in users.AsEnumerable()
                        where user.Email == User.Identity.Name
                        select user.Id;


            var placerecord = db.UserPlace;


            var userplace = from uplace in placerecord.AsEnumerable()
                        where uplace.usersId == queryId.ToString()
                            select uplace.placesId;

            var places = db.TrashPlaces;

            var field = from blah in places.AsEnumerable()
                        where blah.Id == userplace.ToString()
                        select blah.nameOfThePlace;






           TempData["username"] = User.Identity.Name;
            TempData["fieldname"] = field.ToString();
            TempData["datename"] = DateTime.Now;


            List<TrashViewModel> json = (List<TrashViewModel>)TempData["jsonList"];


            return View(json);
    }
```

Would be grateful for help and or/advice what's the best approach towards cascading LINQ.

Thanks!

Comment: You get an IQueryable collection when you access your context entities (like `UserPlace`, `TrashPlaces` etc.). In our queries you casting the IQueryable (which is a collection not in memory, but rather translates to SQL query and is processed by DBMS), to IEnumerable, which loads the results of each entity in memory(meaning you fetched them and they are in context). The outer part will behave on LINQ-to-objects rather than LINQ-to-SQL. Run it first as an IQueryable, then bring your results in memory. Answer below is the one you should follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do all in one (don't enumerate to early by the way, this is not good for performance).

Not sure why you use `ToString()` you shouldn't have to if your ids are of the same type.

```
var query = from u in db.AspNetUsers
            join up in db.db.UserPlace on u.Id equals  up.usersId 
            join tp in db.TrashPlaces on up.placesId equals tp.Id
            where u.Email == User.Identity.Name
            select tp.nameOfThePlace;//or more data if you need to.

var result = query.FirstOrDefault(); //or query.AsEnumerable()
```

Then you can do a null check

```
if (result == null)
```

In your case, for TempData, you may just do

```
TempData["fieldname"] = result == null ? string.Empty : result;
```

or

```
TempData["fieldname"] = result;
```

But then you'll have to check if `TempData["fieldname"]` is not null before using it.
...